# How to fetch max number from the database in ASP.NET Core 6 API or replace the DTO field using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

My requirement is to fetch max number from the database and add +1 to make it different. I can use auto-increment ID but it's different according to the requirement

```
try
{
    logger.LogInformation($"Patient registered successfully");

    var patient = mapper.Map<Patient>(patientCreateDTO);
        
    await _context.Patient.AddAsync(patient);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetPatient", new { id = patient.Id }, patient);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.LogError(e, $" Error performing post in {nameof(PostPatient)}");
    return StatusCode(500, Messages.Error500Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved Getting max Number from the database in asp.net core 6. Replace any DTO field from NULL to Default Value from Controller Side without Request Body

```
  try
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Patient Registred Successfully");
            
            var maxNumber= await _context.Patient.MaxAsync(e => e.Uhid);
            maxNumber+= 1;
          
            var patient = mapper.Map<Patient>(patientCreateDTO);

            if(maxNumber== null)
            {
                maxNumber= 1;
            }   
          
            patient.Uhid = maxNumber;
         
            await _context.Patient.AddAsync(patient);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetPatient", new { id = patient.Id }, patient);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e, $" Error Performing Post in {nameof(PostPatient)}");
            return StatusCode(500, Messages.Error500Message);
          
        }
```